# Why CMake compiles objects with different size?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake for a legacy project and I noticed the binaries (CMake vs originals) have different sizes. I found one reason why the same code is turned into compiled object (.o) files with different size. Here is a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the issue (using Ubuntu 18.04):

**main.cpp** file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // this line changes the size of .o file

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeList.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hello_world)

add_library(app SHARED main.cpp)
```

Then in the `build` directory execute:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ../source
$ make
```

Thanks to the verbose makefile, we can copy the **exact command** sent to the compiler. So, create new `mybuild/CMakeFiles/app.dir` directories (just to match command) and from `mybuild` directory execute:

```
$ /usr/bin/c++ -Dapp_EXPORTS -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/CMakeExample/source/main.cpp
```

Checking the size of both object files we get:

| File | Size |
| --- | --- |
| `build/main.cpp.o` | 42408 |
| `mybuild/main.cpp.o` | 42416 |

**Questions**:

1. Why is there a difference in the size if the compiler is getting the same command?
2. How to fix this (i.e. have the same size from CMake)?

Comment: How about embedded full pathname to the source file?  The build asks for debug symbols `using namespace std;` might affect the symbol names ?

Comment: @RichardCritten, the full pathname to the source file is already there.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think you're into something with the debug symbols. I tried a `Release` build and the size is the same. Now why/how would CMake affect the symbol names in this case?

Comment: I love how people are so choosy about debug info, its size, its format, whether it is deterministic, etc, when really, they are fortunate that it even exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute path of the working directory is written into the debug info. You can observe this like so:

```
$ grep $PWD/build <(strings ./build/CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o)
/home/alexreinking/test/build
```

This accounts for at least two (`my`) of the 8 bytes, the rest of which might be padding / alignment or something else. There are other differences between the files at this point too, including a timestamp, a checksum, etc.

Stripping both files yields bit-for-bit identical results:

```
$ cmp <(strip build/CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o -o -) \
      <(strip mybuild/CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cpp.o -o -) \
    && echo "Files are the same" \
    || echo "Files are different"
Files are the same
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @AlexReinking. Great insight about the absolute path! Building this example from the same `build` directory, both object files have the same size, and the binaries have no differences (without stripping). However, CMake (for legacy project) is still producing different binaries than original (even when building from same dir), probably due to several other reasons. As @RichardCritten suggested, does CMake affect the symbol names? FYI original legacy is built using `-O2 -g` so I need to make sure binaries are bit-for-bit identical without stripping the debug symbols.